# How is this considered immutable?

Tags: java

From my understanding of Java, String is immutable. So the following will not concatenate and only give me the output **app**, proving it is immutable. I get that.

```
String apple = new String("app");
apple.concat("le");
System.out.println(apple);
```

But I am able to change the value of the String after initializing it with some value. Isn't this considered immutable anyway?

```
String orange = "ora";
orange = "orange";
System.out.println(orange);
```

Comment: You should read any good java beginner book

Comment: `orange = "orange";` is (for argument sake) the same as `orange = new String("orange");` (yes, there are some internal/technical differences, but for the sake of the argument)

Comment: "proving it is immutable" - no. It proves that it can return a new (immutable) string which is the concatenation of it (an immutable string) and another (immutable) string..

Comment: Immutable meaning when you do `orange = "orange";` the previous String object "ora" still exists and has not been mutated. "orange" is a new String object created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
orange = "orange";
```

what happens behind the scenes is:

```
orange = new String("orange");
```

That is, `orange`, as a *reference* to a `String`, is modified. It just points to a different `String` instance.

In this statement:

```
apple.concat("le");
```

what happens is that you create a new `String` object which is the result of `apple.concat(new String("le"))`, but you don't assign it...

But then again you are dealing with strings here; strings are one of the few classes in Java which have built-in behaviors, such as:

```
final String x = "a" + "b";
```

which in fact translates to:

```
final String x = new StringBuilder("a").append("b").toString();
```

You have stepped into a hornet's nest.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome... Don't fret over the negative votes, I have fallen victim to this many times :p

Comment: *"what happens behind the scenes is: `orange = new String("orange");`"* I highly doubt that. *"which in fact translates to: `final String x = new StringBuilder("a").append("b").toString();`"* This isn't correct either. Literals aren't concatenated using StringBuilder.

Comment: @Tom yes they are; check the JLS

Comment: I guess you mean the part where it says that compile time constant expressions are evaluated at compile time? I'm not the one, who should check that.

Comment: Quite sad to see that the incorrect part *"`final String x = "a" + "b";` which in fact translates to: `final String x = new StringBuilder("a").append("b").toString();`"* is still in the answer :(.

Answer (score 7):

The **Object** is immutable, the **reference** is not. You can change the reference as often as you like with *orange = "Orange"* but you are not changing the object. You are merely letting go of the old one and attaching the reference to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of the `String` class are immutable. The `apple` *variable* is not immutable, but it would be if you declared it `final`.

For example, the following code is *mutating* the object:

```
Person p = new Person("John");
p.setName("Jenny"); // <-- mutating
```

Immutable objects (like `String`, `Integer`, ...) have no method that change the state of the object.

In contrast, the following code is changing the value of `p`, but is not mutating any objects:

```
Person p = new Person("John");
p = new Person("Jenny");
```

`p` is simply updated to reference a different `Person` object. The original "John" object still exists (until garbage collected).

Now, if `p` was defined as `final`, then it (the variable) would be immutable too:

```
final Person p = new Person("John");
// Cannot: p = new Person("Jenny");
```

In your particular case, `concat` does not mutate the `String`, it creates a new string and returns it, so you need to:

```
String apple = new String("app");
apple = apple.concat("le");
System.out.println(apple); // prints "apple"
```

Here the variable is updated, but not the `String` object.

Comment: While this is true, the level of the question would dictate that an example be given (no offense meant to the OP here)... Especially since here we are dealing with string constants which undergo a special treatment by the compiler.

Comment: @fge Actually, your answer is wrong, because `orange = "orange"` does not mean `orange = new String("orange")`. If it did, then `a = "X"; b = "X"` would assign two different objects to `a` and `b`, and it doesn't. They both get the *same* object reference.

Comment: This is only a side effect of the JRE implementation... But the real problem here, and what your answer fails to mention, is that it is the _reference_ (`orange`) which is, in fact, mutable.

Comment: @fge it's not just an implementation detail, it's required by JLS 15.28

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, an immutable object is:

> an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

However, you are not *modifying* the original orange `String object` (`"ora"`): you are creating a new `String object` (`"orange"`), and this **new** object is being *assigned* to a variable.

---

#### Easy as cake

If that doesn't make sense, think of it this way. Supposing some `Object` was a block of chocolate cake, you can add icing or cut out parts of this cake without actually changing the identity of the cake. However, if you wanted to change it to a red velvet cake, you have to make a *new* cake, because you cannot *modify* a chocolate cake to make it into a red velvet cake (for practical purposes) the original. An immutable object means you cannot cut, or ice... that "cake", but you can replace it with a new cake.

Comment: I believe the straightforward answer is people go trigger happy when they can down vote without the need to explain themselves.

Answer (score 0):

`orange = "orange"` only means that `orange` is pointing to a new `String` instance instead of the old one (`"ora"`).

Immutability means that you cannot change an object's state once it has been created. You haven't changed the state of the string instance that `orange` is referring to; you just made it refer to a new instance. Changing an object's state requires you to either call a method on that object that changes its state, or modify one of its publicly-accessible properties.

You're also confusing immutability of objects with immutability of references. To make a reference immutable (i.e., make sure you cannot make it point to something else once it has been initialized) you use the `final` keyword.

So if you had:

```
final String orange = "ora";
orange = "orange";
```

You would now get an error because the reference is immutable and cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

The **Object** is immutable while the **reference** is not. You can change the reference but not object.

### Adding an example to make us more clear

```
String orange1 = "ora";
String orange2 = orange1;
System.out.println("orange1: " + orange1 +  " , orange2: " + orange2);
System.out.println("----------------------");
orange2 = "orange";
System.out.println("orange1: " + orange1 +  " , orange2: " + orange2);
```